# How to get the time left of a previously set alarm without changing its value?

Tags: c, unix, signals, alarm

Is it possible to know how much time is left for an alarm which has been previously set using the `alarm()` system call, but without changing its current value?
If it is possible, how can I get this?

Comment: On Linux, you can read `/proc/timer_list` and look for a line that contains `do_setitimer, yourprocessname/yourpid`. The following line will be something like `# expires at 2706742298201-2706742298201 nsecs [in 201647627253 to 201647627253 nsecs]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Modern alternatives like [`timer_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_gettime.html) permit this kind of interrogation of pending alarms, but the venerable [`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html) call does not.

You can clear and re-set the `alarm()` as you suggested in your post, or, if you set the `alarm()` yourself, you can of course compute and remember the expected expiry time.  (Caveat:  the `alarm()` call has only one-second precision.)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the number of seconds remaining by calling alarm(0) and looking at the return value.  That doesn't meet your requirement that it not change the current value though, because calling alarm(0) cancels any pending alarm.  You could call alarm again, passing in the remaining number of seconds you just read, and that would reset the alarm.  The problem is it's not very precise, and would not exactly mimic the behavior of the original alarm call because the time resolution is only one second.  Your timing could be off by nearly a whole second if you do this, but maybe that's OK.

From the looks of your question it appears that you may have already thought about all these issues, and have read the man pages just as I have.  I still haven't found an exact answer to your question, but I wanted to propose my inexact answer in case that's good enough for you.